# Catch Thunderous AND Landorous?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In Pokemon Alpha Sapphire and Omega Ruby, If You catch Thunderous in the Storm Clouds Mirage Spot using the Eon Flute, than will the Storm Clouds come back so you can catch Landerous, or Tornadous?

Comment: You catch thunderous in one game, and landerous in the other. Once you have both on one game you can catch tornadous.